# Spotify Play Button in ePub 3.0 eBook

Tags: button, spotify, playback, epub

I am using InDesign CS6, Sigil, Textwrangler and ePub Zip-Unzip to produce ePub 3.0 eBooks.  I would like "something-like" a Spotify Play Button but for ePub 3.0 eBooks, not for a Web site.  I wish to code this Spotify Play Button in the ePub 3.0 eBook allowing play of a Spotify sound track either by streaming over the internet or tracks previously downloaded to Spotify.app on an iPad. From what I've read about ePub 3.0 (HTML5 for Publishers by Sandy Kleinfeld and EPUB 3 Best Practices by Garrish & Gylling), it seems that an  is no good for ePub 3.0.

Does anyone have any suggestions or information on this?  Thanks, Charlie

Answer (score 0):

You won't have access to any data inside the Spotify.app, so that's a dead end.

If you can do the required user validation through simple web requests for streaming it might be possible in an ePub, but I doubt it.